# Does over refrigerator cabinet need support at both ends?

Tags: walls, refrigerator, cabinets, support

We're planning to replace our refrigerator in the next couple of years. I have found that I could get a much larger appliance if it weren't for one "wall" that sort of makes a cove for the existing fridge on the right side. It is a piece of 3/4" thick board, it is attached to the floor and the cabinet above. The cabinet is attached to the ceiling, and a fully framed wall structure on the left side. The 3/4" inch "wall" appears to be attached to the bottom of the cabinet above with what looks like to be some finishing lumber, not more than 1/4" thick. I can't visibly tell what is attaching it.

I'm really just wondering if the whole wall can be removed, but keep the cabinet. Does it have enough support from the ceiling and other wall, as well as the back wall?

[image: Side of Refrigerator with red arrow pointing at wall to be removed] [image: showing connection of wall board with right side of overhead cabinet]

[image: Interior left side of cabinet. Arrows noting screws. Red arrows indicate screws that are repeated in the image of the right side.]

[image: Interior right side of cabinet. Arrows noting screws. Red arrows indicate screws that are repeated in the image of the left side. Note one screw through front facing up through into ceiling]

Comment: It will depend on the construction of the cabinet.  Most wall cabinets are only supported/attached to the wall in the back with screws into the studs.  That wall might be used to support or just to close in the fridge.

Comment: Adding shelf brackets to support the bottom of the cabinet might be an option. Wish I'd thought of that before replacing my fridge; could have squeezed in a bigger one

Comment: So the new fridge will be wider?  Partly where the low brown cabinet is now with the back of the fridge exposed behind?

Comment: @jay613 Yes the new fridge would be about 3" wider. However, it would not be exposed from behind. It's hard to tell in the photo but the 3/4" board is inset from the wall behind by another 1 1/4" as well. I would gain 2" without that board, plus the couple inches available around the existing 33" fridge. It's probably technically too close, but if that board were flush with the wall behind, I could probably actually still fit a 36" fridge. If it isn't there at all, I can still have the back fully covered, the side fully exposed, while meeting recommended ventilation requirements.

Comment: Odds are really good that if you empty the cabinet, you'll see 4 screws (maybe more) going though the back of it into the wall. You _might_ see 1 or 2 screws going through the face frame connecting it to the cabinet to the left. These really aren't structural nor do they support much weight - they simply keep the cabinet fronts flush. That piece of wood you see scabbed onto the inside of the bottom of the cabinet is doing the same with the false wall on the right - it's 99.9% for alignment so it looks good from the outside. That wall _might_ be carrying some weight, but not much.

Comment: Can you get us photos of the interior of the cabinet, particularly the top back?

Comment: @Huesmann added to main post.

Comment: @Stephen hard to be sure; if the back of the cabinet is 1/2" ply, it should be fine, though I'd prefer a nailing strip.  But it *is* screwed to the ceiling, apparently—hopefully that's at a joist.  If you can confirm that screw goes * through* the frame and into a joist (unscrew and check length, use stud finder to check for joist), I wouldn't have any compunction in removing the fridge "wall."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether it **does** have adequate support is unknown.

It certainly **can be** adequately supported from behind and above.

Whether that involves adding some hardware or not would be something for you to determine after you investigate how it is attached now.

It's not much of a structure, but even *not much of a structure* can provide significant support if the other supports are lacking.

Comment: Thanks! That's kind of what I was thinking. I will have someone do some more evaluating, but wasn't sure if the "can be" was feasible or not.

Comment: Cabinets generally are happy to be hung on the wall. Clear out enough stuff to see just how many screws you’re can see going through the back of the cabinet into the wall, preferably into studs.